# Win7Enterprise: Outlook, reserving a resource

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

This common problem is [documented here](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/797007-kb2956087-changes-outlook-2013-room-booking). Using Windows7 Enterprise: When clicking on a time-slot of a resource in Outlook.Calendar, I get this message.  The link show discussion but has no apparent solutions.

```
  You don't have permission to create an entry in this folder.
  Right-click the folder, and then click Properties to see your permissions.
```

When I right click the resource as suggested, I get the second error.

I was able to reserve resources, before getting this new Win7 Enterprise laptop.

[image: Outlook error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solutions *are* in the thread you linked.

Anyhow, this is a design change that was done on purpose by MS, it's actually correcting it, as clicking the Resource calendars was never the official way to do it.

To deal with it you either revert by uninstall KB2956087, block it and all it predecessors (bad idea), or you teach your users the proper way to book resources...

The way you're intended to do it is to schedule a new Meeting in your Calendar, and then click the `To...` button and add your resources as "Resources":

[image]

More info from Microsoft: [How to direct book a resource in Outlook](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/kb/291616)

Note this article is for Office 2003, and the instructions still say to do it as described here, not by double-clicking the calendar...  As a matter of fact, all instructions I can find online (dating back to [Outlook 2000](http://www.slipstick.com/outlook/calendar/scheduling-resources-outlook/)) all say the same thing:  You "direct book" resources by inviting them to the meeting you're creating (in your calendar).